# MySQL nested select. First entry & Last entry with midnight hour overlap. How?

Tags: mysql, sql

**I have the following table:**

[image: table]

**I have created the following nested SELECT queries.**

```
SELECT 

(SELECT utl_dtstamp FROM tbl_user_time_log
WHERE user_id = 465605 AND utl_event = 'CLOCK IN'
ORDER BY utl_dtstamp ASC
LIMIT 1) AS 'First Entry',

(SELECT utl_dtstamp FROM tbl_user_time_log
WHERE user_id = 465605 AND utl_event = 'CLOCK OUT' 
ORDER BY utl_dtstamp DESC
LIMIT 1) AS 'Last Entry';
```

**And the result is this:**

[image: result]

What I can't figure out is how to SELECT the first entry of this project by user_id together with the last entry of this project by user_id if the user ends up working through midnight.

**I've also created these 2 additional SELECTS based on DAY(NOW())** but it appears that if the user clocks in to a new project after midnight, DAY(NOW()) will begin to perceive this user's first entry as of midnight forward...

```
SELECT 

(SELECT utl_dtstamp FROM tbl_user_time_log
WHERE user_id = 465605 AND DAY(utl_dtstamp) = DAY(NOW()) 
ORDER BY utl_dtstamp ASC
LIMIT 1) AS 'First Entry';

***LAST stamp BY USER so far TODAY.

(SELECT utl_dtstamp FROM tbl_user_time_log
WHERE user_id = 465605 AND DAY(utl_dtstamp) = DAY(NOW()) 
ORDER BY utl_dtstamp DESC
LIMIT 1) AS 'Last Entry';
```

Any ideas, pointers, samples would be fantastic.

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: I need the amount of ellapsed seconds as an integer between the two.